# What does a series of ^@ in the syslog mean?

Tags: linux, syslog, ubuntu-20.04

Our server did not react to pings anymore since around 23:49 yesterday until we restarted it at 7:09 am today. These are the last things we saw in the syslog:

The machine runs on Ubuntu 20.04 with plenty of docker containers for CI.

[image: Syslog excerpt]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/356981/character-in-syslog

Comment: Thanks, so we will try a mem check